# How to display geoJSON from an URL in a layer?

Tags: qgis, geojson, json

I am looking for some type of plugin or code which would allow me to add a geojson URL, define the areas to input the lat/long variables from the visible Qgis canvas map and call/render the results within Qgis. Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This works with the default "Add vector layer" dialog

[image]

You'll have to add the bounding box to the query manually if necessary.

It's also not difficult to import GeoJSON into QGIS. For an example covering point geometries see ["Tweets to QGIS"](http://underdark.wordpress.com/2011/10/01/tweets-to-qgis/).

Comment: great info there thanks. I think I remember reading somewhere about a method or plugin which would let you define a folder where any tiles/data files would be stored upon initial load + providing the ability ensure previously loaded data does not get downloaded twice. Any idea on how this is achieved?