# How to load GeoJSON files directly onto QGIS?

Tags: qgis, postgis, shapefile, geojson, ogr2ogr

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Plugin or script to get QGIS to display geoJSON in a layer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17035/plugin-or-script-to-get-qgis-to-display-geojson-in-a-layer)

Is there a way to do this? Or is there a way i can put it onto PostGIS and then load it onto QGIS? I actually used ogr2ogr to load the GeoJSON to Postgis. After that I used ogr2ogr again to pull it out as shapefiles (Using SQL conditions to seperate different geometry types since shapefiles can only hold one geometry type). I then loaded these shapefiles onto QGIS. I want to know if i can directly achieve this without using ogr2ogr or even PostGIS?